# How to return a list of map keys if they are true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following map and I need to return 2 lists.

The lists will contain the map `KEYS`, one with only true `values` and another list with only the false or null `values`.

```
Map<int, bool?> weekdaymap = {
      0: _habit.wd1,
      1: _habit.wd2,
      2: _habit.wd3,
      3: _habit.wd4,
      4: _habit.wd5,
      5: _habit.wd6,
      6: _habit.wd7,
    };
```

I'm new to dart/flutter and I can't find the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<int> trueKeys = [];
 List<int> falseKeys = [];
 weekdaymap.forEach((k, v) {
       if(v == true){
         trueKeys.add(k);
      }else if(v == false){
         falseKeys.add(k);
      }else{
         //Handle For null cases
      }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained the question wrong.

It doesn't matter if it's map and you take the Key or `List [boolhabit1,boolhabit2,boolhabit3, etc]` and you take the index, what I need are two lists, one that contains all the keys or index with a true value and another with all those with all false values

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I have updated it.

Comment: Working!! It's simple but I had not realized that it could be done like this!! thank you!