# flutter why my provider is reinitialized?

Tags: flutter, initialization, riverpod

I am founding it in my code.
I didn't initialize diceNumberProvider as -1 especially in onChanged method of TextField.
And instead of being (-1), I want and guess it should be (-2) as changed value.
Is there some lines I initialize my state in code?

**shakeState.dart**

```
//1. 흔들었을때,refresh 버튼을 눌렀을때 random 인덱스값
final diceNumberProvider = StateNotifierProvider<DiceNumberNotifier, int>(
  (ref) {
    //홈화면 스위치로 필터한 리스트 개수 반영
    final homeScreenRecipes = ref.watch(homeScreenRecipesProvider);
    return DiceNumberNotifier(length: homeScreenRecipes.length);
  },
);

class DiceNumberNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  DiceNumberNotifier({required this.length}) : super(-1);

  int length;

  //주사위를 굴립니다.
  void roll() {
    debugPrint('0~$length개 요리');
    // 시작은 (-1 , 0~1114)이고 홈화면에서 필터하고난 뒤 리스트 수 안에서 인덱스가 나오도록 함
    try {
      state = Random().nextInt(length);
    } catch (e) {
      //레시피 필터 결과 개수가 0개일때 에러가 나므로 -2로 넣어준다.
      debugPrint('shakeState roll()에서 에러남: $e');
      state = -2;
    }
    debugPrint('$state번째 요리');
  }
}

//2. ShakeDetector Provider
final shakeDetectorProvider = StateProvider(
  (ref) => ShakeDetector.waitForStart(
    shakeThresholdGravity: 2,
    onPhoneShake: () {
      ref.read(diceNumberProvider.notifier).roll();
    },
  ),
);
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int diceNumber = ref.watch(diceNumberProvider);
    final List<Recipe> recipeList = ref.watch(homeScreenRecipesProvider);
    final Recipe? currentRecipe = diceNumber == -1 || diceNumber == -2
        ? null
        : recipeList.elementAt(diceNumber);
    if (currentRecipe != null) {
      debugPrint('분류: ${currentRecipe.rcppat2}, 요리명: ${currentRecipe.rcpnm}');
    }
    Map<String, bool> categories = ref.watch(homeScreenRecipeCategoryProvider);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.9),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const ListTile(
                title: Text('필터)'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: myController,
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                          hintText: "예:두부 버섯(띄어쓰기로 구분합니다)",
                          fillColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        onChanged: (ingredients) {
                          bool a = ref.exists(diceNumberProvider);

                          ref
                              .read(homeScreenRecipesProvider.notifier)
                              .filterList(ingredients, categories);

                          debugPrint('다이스넘버:$diceNumber');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Text('${recipeList.length.toString()}개'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              // https://flutterguide.com/how-to-use-spread-operator-in-flutter/
              ...categories.keys
                  .map(
                    (key) => SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                      title: Text(key),
                      value: categories[key]!,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          categories[key] = value;
                          // 체크박스 토글시 리스트 필터를 적용
                          ref
                              .read(homeScreenRecipesProvider.notifier)
                              .filterList(myController.text, categories);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              const BuymeacoffeeWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ContentWidget(
          currentRecipe: currentRecipe,
          diceNumber: diceNumber,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(diceNumberProvider.notifier).roll();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class ContentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContentWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.currentRecipe,
    required this.diceNumber,
  });

  final Recipe? currentRecipe;
  final int diceNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (diceNumber == -1) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          '흔들어주세요!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
        ),
      );
    } else if (diceNumber == -2) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          '조건에 맞는 레시피가 없습니다.',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TopWidget(currentRecipe: currentRecipe),
            ),
            BottomButtonsWidget(currentRecipe: currentRecipe),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

class TopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.currentRecipe,
  });

  final Recipe? currentRecipe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child: Image.network(
            currentRecipe!.attfilenomain!,
            loadingBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Widget child,
              ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress,
            ) {
              if (loadingProgress == null) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    child,
                    Positioned(
                      right: 8,
                      top: 8,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.favorite_outline,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
              return SizedBox(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                        ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                            loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                        : null,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        Text(
          currentRecipe!.rcpnm!,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge?.copyWith(
                color: Colors.black,
                // fontFamily: 'BlackHanSans',
              ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**homeScreenState.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:whateatgo2/model/recipe.dart';

//1. 홈 화면에 switch 상태 관리
final homeScreenRecipeCategoryProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>(
  (ref) => {
    '밥': true,
    '후식': true,
    '반찬': true,
    '일품': true,
    '국&찌개': true,
    '기타': true,
  },
);

//2. 홈 화면에 후보군 리스트(초기값은 모든 리스트)
final homeScreenRecipesProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<HomeScreenFilteredRecipeListNotifier, List<Recipe>>(
  (ref) => HomeScreenFilteredRecipeListNotifier(),
);

class HomeScreenFilteredRecipeListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Recipe>> {
  HomeScreenFilteredRecipeListNotifier()
      : super(Hive.box<Recipe>('recipeBox').values.toList());

  List<Recipe> filterList(String keywords, Map<String, bool> categories) {
    //'밥', '후식', '반찬', '일품',  '국&찌개' 분류 SwitchListTile들 중에서
    // 스위치 온 된(true) key 값만 가져온다. (국&찌개, 후식 등)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309888/how-to-return-a-list-of-map-keys-if-they-are-true
    List<String> trueCategories = [];
    categories.forEach((category, isSwitchOn) {
      if (isSwitchOn == true) {
        trueCategories.add(category);
      }
    });

    //검색 키워드 리스트. 띄어쓰기 기준
    List<String> keywordList = keywords.split(' ');

    //검색어를 포함하고 & 스위치 온 된 음식 분류를 포함하고있는 레시피를 담을 리스트
    List<Recipe> filtered = []; //최종 리스트
    List<Recipe> tmpFiltered = [];

    for (String category in trueCategories) {
      //1차 애벌 필터
      tmpFiltered += Hive.box<Recipe>('recipeBox')
          .values
          .toList()
          .where(
            (element) =>
                (element.rcpnm!.contains(keywordList[0])) || //메뉴명
                (element.hashtag!.contains(keywordList[0])) || //해쉬태그
                (element.rcppartsdtls!.contains(keywordList[0])), //재료정보
          )
          .where((recipe) => recipe.rcppat2 == category) //요리종류
          .toList();
    }

    //키워드가 하나만 있으면 여기서 마무리
    if (keywordList.length == 1) {
      filtered = tmpFiltered;
      state = filtered;
      return filtered;
    }

    //더 많으면 keyword 개수만큼 nested filter 해준다.
    for (int i = 0; i < keywordList.length; i++) {
      tmpFiltered = tmpFiltered
          .where(
            (recipe) =>
                (recipe.rcpnm!.contains(keywordList[i])) || //메뉴명
                (recipe.hashtag!.contains(keywordList[i])) || //해쉬태그
                (recipe.rcppartsdtls!.contains(keywordList[i])), //재료정보
          )
          .toList();
    }

    filtered = tmpFiltered;
    state = filtered;
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

I guess the diceNumberProvider is disposed and recreated.
How to I check it?

My repo is
https://github.com/kangsudal/whateatgo/blob/main/lib/screen/home_screen.dart

Thanks.

Comment: so your question is : why `diceNumberProvider` state value == -1 instead of -2?

Comment: Yes. Exactly, why text widget shows 흔들어주세요 instead of 조건에 맞는 레시피가 없습니다.

Comment: Can it be `homeScreenRecipesProvider` changed? Because this will lead to `diceNumberProvider` to be recreated, since it is watching it.

Comment: you initialize with this `DiceNumberNotifier({required this.length}) : super(-1);` , `super(-1)` is the initial state, so you change it with `roll()` function and expect it to be -2? sorry i still dont get your question

Comment: I don't want to recreate diceNumberProvider. do you know how to create once it from my code @StefanGaller?